# How to get enum's numeric value?

Tags: java, enums

Suppose you have

```
public enum Week {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY
}
```

How can one get `int` representing that Sunday is 0, Wednesday is 3 etc?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
Week week = Week.SUNDAY;

int i = week.ordinal();
```

Be careful though, that this value will change if you alter the order of enum constants in the declaration. One way of getting around this is to self-assign an int value to all your enum constants like this:

```
public enum Week 
{
     SUNDAY(0),
     MONDAY(1)

     private static final Map<Integer,Week> lookup 
          = new HashMap<Integer,Week>();

     static {
          for(Week w : EnumSet.allOf(Week.class))
               lookup.put(w.getCode(), w);
     }

     private int code;

     private Week(int code) {
          this.code = code;
     }

     public int getCode() { return code; }

     public static Week get(int code) { 
          return lookup.get(code); 
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 for providing a nice answer where a 1-liner would have been sufficient

Comment: One liner: `final int i = Week.SUNDAY.ordinal();`

Answer (score 9):

You can call:

```
MONDAY.ordinal()
```

but personally I would add an attribute to the `enum` to store the value, initialize it in the `enum` constructor and add a function to get the value. This is better because the value of `MONDAY.ordinal` can change if the `enum` constants are moved around.

Answer (score 2):

[Take a look at the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) it is usually a decent place to start. Though I would not have guessed without having run into this before that you call ENUM_NAME.ordinal()

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Simply use the **ordinal** method of enum object.

```
public class Gtry {
  enum TestA {
    A1, A2, A3
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(TestA.A2.ordinal());
    System.out.println(TestA.A1.ordinal());
    System.out.println(TestA.A3.ordinal());
  }

}
```

**API:**

```
/**
     * Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position
     * in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned
     * an ordinal of zero).
     *
     * Most programmers will have no use for this method.  It is
     * designed for use by sophisticated enum-based data structures, such
     * as {@link java.util.EnumSet} and {@link java.util.EnumMap}.
     *
     * @return the ordinal of this enumeration constant
     */
    public final int ordinal() {
        return ordinal;
    }
```

Comment: 5 years late and not better than any of the previous answers

Comment: @Trilarion, Now you are 5+ years late do you have any better answers? ;)